# shiny - Multi-panel output needs to appear larger

Tags: r, plot, size, shiny

I have code to display 4 panels of output through `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`. And, I am able to generate the same successfully with side bar input in Shiny. However, the overall size of the output covering the 4 panels is quite small and appears congested. How do I make Shiny output the plot to occupy maximum space?

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2),
    xpd=NA)

plot(monthRange, dPerMonth, 
     type="l",
     xlab="Months",
     ylab="Count")

plot(monthRange, iPerMonth, 
     type="l",
     xlab="Months",
     ylab="Count")

plot(monthRange, euroPerMonth/1000, 
     type="l",
     xlab="Months",
     ylab="€ (000)")    

plot(monthRange, euroDPerMonth/1000, 
     type="l",
     xlab="Months",
     ylab="€ (000)")
```

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example, please provide `server.r` `ui.r` and the data.

Comment: I will paste that shortly. However, note that, I am training myself in R and this is an example that I extended from some web page. So, nothing grandiose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
ui.R
...
plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot",  width = "100%"),
...

server.R
...
output$main_plot <- renderPlot(
  {plot(x, y)}, 
  height = 600, width = 800
)
...
```